# docker ignores .dockerignore file

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and yet trying to understand how to use it. Everything's going well except one thing. Somehow docker ignores `.dockerignore` file every time and still copies all the files inside the container (at least I think that's the problem).

So I have `Dockerfile` in my directory:

```
FROM elixir

RUN mkdir /elixir_edu
COPY . /elixir_edu
WORKDIR /elixir_edu

VOLUME /elixir_edu

CMD ["bash"]
```

which works perfectly well (I mean, I can build an image and so on) and I have `.dockerignore` file:

```
docker.sh
.DS_Store
.tags
```

But after I build an image with `docker build . -t elixir_edu` and run it with `` docker run -it --rm -v `pwd`:/elixir_edu elixir_edu ``, I find all the files listed in `.dockerignore` inside my container. What do I do wrong?

Comment: You're mounting the working directory, why wouldn't those files be there? Docker's ignore file is for the build context, not volume mounting, and there's really no point putting a few small files in it; the point is to minimise copying by excluding e.g. dependencies, build outputs and other *large* files/directories.

Comment: aaah, got it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @jonrsharpe explained in comments, everything actually works as it is. My image, if I run it without mounting a directory to it, doesn't have the files listed in `.dockerignore`.